# I can't use Kotlin for Serenity-bdd

Tags: kotlin, serenity-bdd

I try use kotlin for my tests with serenity-bed framework, but this don't work
for example

```
public class EndUserSteps {

    var dictionaryPage: DictionaryPage = null!!

    @Step
    fun enters(keyword: String) {
        dictionaryPage.enter_keywords(keyword)
    }

    @Step
    fun starts_search() {
        dictionaryPage.lookup_terms()
    }

    @Step
    fun should_see_definition(definition: String) {
        assertThat(dictionaryPage.definitions, hasItem(containsString(definition)))
    }

    @Step
    fun is_the_home_page() {
        dictionaryPage.open()
    }

    @Step
    fun looks_for(term: String) {
        enters(term)
        starts_search()
    }
}
```

Other code has written in Java!

output:
(net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.StepInitialisationException: Failed to create step library for EndUserSteps:Cannot subclass final class class ru.tinkoff.atesting.steps.serenity.EndUserSteps)

can you help me?
Have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kotlin classes [don't allow subclassing by default](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance) (equivalent of Java's `final`). To allow subclassing you need to mark them as `open`. (`open class X`)

> The open annotation on a class is the opposite of Java's final: it allows others to inherit from this class. By default, all classes in Kotlin are final, which corresponds to Effective Java, Item 17: Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it. -- [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance)

Comment: you are right!
Modifier *Open* before class and really solved the problem of launching

Comment: Hey Alex, I am also trying Serenity with Kotlin. Can you please help? Can you share some sample working repo?